# Best way to Querying TypedDataSet

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have to done optimization of my code. I am using typedDataset. For querying type dataset what is the best method.

Like: Linq or any thing else..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what entity you want get at the end of the query.
If you want to get some on-fly created types, then use the Linq queries.
If you just want to have a code analog for sql-statements, use methods of the Dataset, DataTable and so on.

Answer (score 0):

what do you define as **best**?

if you mean best=flexible i would use dataviews on datatables where you can set filter (similar to sql-where) and sorting (similar to sql-order-by). These values are simple strings that can be stored in setting-files.

however if performance is an issue for you then the database should do the filter/sort stuff for you that is independent of datasets

Answer (score 0):

If you think about performance then take a look at this comparison

http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/performance-benchmarks-linq-vs-sqldatareader-dataset-linq-compiled-queries-part-2